# How to create a leveling system with discord.py with python?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I tried to make a levelling system into my bot but something went wrong. The level rose after each message and not after the specified parameter. How to make it work properly? How to create a leveling system with `discord.py`?

Here is my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message( message ):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        member = message.author.name
        msg_len = len(message.content)
        rand_number_1 = randint( 1, 10 )
        exp_first = msg_len * rand_number_1
        coins_first = exp_first // 10
        data_levels_member_first = { 'exp': 0, 'coins': 0, 'level': 0}
        filename = f'./Data/Profiles/Profile{message.author.name}{message.guild}.json'
        try:
            data = load( filename )
        except Exception:
            dump( filename, data_levels_member_first )
            data = load( filename )
        exp_member = data['exp']
        coins_member = data['coins']
        lvl_member = data['level']
        exp = exp_first + exp_member
        coins = coins_first + coins_member
        lvl = exp ** (1/4)
        if lvl_member < lvl:
            lvl_member += 1
            print('You lvl up!')
        data_levels_member = { 'exp': exp, 'coins': coins, 'level': lvl_member}
        dump( filename, data_levels_member )
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your existing code, any tracebacks if needed, and your intended behavior (like how much XP to the next level for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a level sytem code that might help you:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    await client.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1


async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp


async def level_up(users, user, message):
    with open('levels.json', 'r') as g:
        levels = json.load(g)
    experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
    lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}')
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end

@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        id = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'You are at level {lvl}!')
    else:
        id = member.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is at level {lvl}!')
```

Comment: It restricts old members.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really caution against using a json file as a database. Json files tend to get corrupted on overwrite. There are a ton of cautionary tales of developers who have fallen into that trap and gotten burned. For a lightweight, quick solution, I'd recommend using sqlite. It's a built-in module in python and is much more stable and secure than a json file. A very simple sqlite3 example with comments (intents not included):

```
import sqlite3
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member): ###add a row in the db for the new member when they join
   user = member.id
   conn = sqlite3.connect('your_db_here.db')
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute('INSERT INTO table_name_here("userid", "xp", "level")VALUES(user, 0, 0)')
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
   await member.send("Your welcome message here")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author.id
    conn = sqlite3.connect('your_db_here.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT xp, level FROM table_name_here WHERE userid = ?')
    results = cur.fetchone()
    row = results[0] ### results will be a list and since you're only fetching one record in this instance, you only need the first index
    old_xp = row[0] ##the first item in the index, in this case, xp
    old_level = row[1] ## the second item in the index, in this case, level
    new_xp = old_xp + 1
    if new_xp == 25: #this is where you set the threshold for leveling up to the first level
        new_level = 1
    else:
        new_level = old_level
    ###add more logic here for successive level-ups
    cur.execute('UPDATE table_name_here SET xp = ?, level = ? WHERE userid = ?', (new_xp, new_level, user)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    ### here is where you'd put any sort of messaging if a person levels up or however you'd like to set it.
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
import discord

try:
    with open("users.json") as fp:
        users = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    users = {}

def save_users():
    with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_points(user: discord.User, points: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in users:
        users[id] = {}
    users[id]["points"] = users[id].get("points", 0) + points
    print("{} now has {} points".format(user.name, users[id]["points"]))
    save_users()

def get_points(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in users:
        return users[id].get("points", 0)
    return 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    print("{} sent a message".format(message.author.name))
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!lvl"):
        msg = "You have {} points!".format(get_points(message.author))
        await client.process_commands(message.channel, msg)
    add_points(message.author, 1)

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it. Never post code on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I've made one for you. It's server specific as well

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        print('function load')
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
            print('file load')
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)

        with open('level.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await client.process_commands(message)




async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send('{} has leveled up to Level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end


@client.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):

    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      with open('level.json','r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar_url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working one:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os
import json
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
##### START LEVEL COMMAND #####
 
with open("users.json", "ab+") as ab:
    ab.close()
    f = open('users.json','r+')
    f.readline()
    if os.stat("users.json").st_size == 0:
      f.write("{}")
      f.close()
    else:
      pass
 
with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
  users = json.load(f)
 
@bot.event    
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await add_experience(users, message.author)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
            await bot.process_commands(message)
 
async def add_experience(users, user):
  if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 0
  users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += 6
  print(f"{users[f'{user.id}']['level']}")
 
async def level_up(users, user, message):
  experience = users[f'{user.id}']["experience"]
  lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']["level"]
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
  if lvl_start < lvl_end:
    await message.channel.send(f':tada: {user.mention} has reached level {lvl_end}. Congrats! :tada:')
    users[f'{user.id}']["level"] = lvl_end
 
@bot.command()
async def rank(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
  if member == None:
    userlvl = users[f'{ctx.author.id}']['level']
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You are at level {userlvl}!')
  else:
    userlvl2 = users[f'{member.id}']['level']
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} is at level {userlvl2}!')
 
##### END LEVEL COMMAND #####
 
bot.run(TOKEN)
```